# Firebase - Web. Can not display logged user's picture

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not able to display the picture of a logged user with email/password inside an `<img>` tag. I could display correctly the email,uid and all the details but the picture. This is the code:

HTML:

```
<img id="user-image">
```

Js:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var picture;
  if (userId) {
    picture = userId.photoURL;
    document.getElementById("user-image").src = picture;
  } else {
    //Nothing;
  }
});
```

When I go to the console I get error 404/null. Yes, the user Do have a picture ,I tried already with the exact path of the image file and it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that picture variable has some value by printing it in your console?

Comment: Can you check if you're on an HTTPS connection and if the URL is an HTTP link? Some browsers might block it as it poses a security risk

Comment: @mark922 The value is null, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you call `firebase.auth().currentUser;` when you already have the user as a parameter of the function that is triggered on change?

What do you get if you do as follows:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var picture = user.photoURL;
    console.log(picture). // <- check in you console that you get the correct url
    document.getElementById("user-image").src = picture;
  } else {
    //Nothing;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot cleaning the code and was calling the user twice. Anyway , checking the console it gives me: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). The url displayed is: pathofmyweb/null

Comment: What is the AuthProvider used to authenticate this user?

Comment: Gmail in this case, but it could be any other because I'm aiming to register users by email/password instead of Facebook,Phone,Google,etc.

Comment: You probably know it but, by default, a user authenticated via email/password AuthProvider will not have a photo.

Comment: Think I will give up and just display another kind of data.